# reply not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope

Why this code doesn't work?

```
void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *red = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("someurl/to/file")));
    QObject::connect(red, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readingReadyBytes()));
    QObject::connect(red, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
}

void MainWindow::readingReadyBytes() {
    QFile file("C:\\test.bin");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(red->read(red->bytesAvailable()));
    file.close();
}
```

QT throws error: 'red' was not declared in this scope
     file.write(red->read(red->bytesAvailable()));
                ^

Comment: Probably because `red` is not an atribute of MainWindow, or a globally accessible variable.

Comment: @Kamil Klimek no need to be rude. I have basic C++ knowledge, but i'm new to Objects and classes.

Comment: I'm not rude. I'm pointing you out that you lack basic C++ knowledge - scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `red` as a class member not in `void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked` function, Then you can assign a value to it in `on_startButton_clicked` functon, so:

Declare `red` as class member :

```
// in your MainWindow class
QNetworkReply *red;
```

Assign value to it in `on_startButton_clicked` method:

```
...
red = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("someurl/to/file")));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

because `red` is local to `on_startButton_clicked()`. 
If you are trying to download and save a file, your code will not work as you are creating the file and closing it every time `readingReadyBytes()` is called.
as suggested by ABFORCE you should declare `red` as member.
Then you should connect the event `finished()` of `QNetworkReply` to a slot that closes the file.